# Number of automorphisms of binary tree

Tags: graph-theory

I've been assigned with a task of creating a tree $T$ for which $|AUT(T)|=2^n$. Is this possible? I know how to construct a tree for which $|AUT(T)|=2^{{2^n}-1}$ but I'm having troubles with the assigned one. Could you please help me?

Comment: What is $n$? Is it the number of nodes in the tree? The number of leaves? The depth?

Comment: You've accepted an answer that constructs a tree that is **not** binary. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root has $n$ children, the first child has two children, the second has one & then two leaves, the third has one that has one & then two leaves , and so on ...

[image]